# How to use Swift extensions functions inside initializers?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to extend my **SKScene** Swift classes to create a **SpriteKit Node** using the textures from an loaded atlas and set the node's name at the same time saving me the lines I need to use for every other node, and I'm using it as extension because I don't want to write the same method in every class I make. Also, I have to create the method as class method or I get the same error at init.

This is my extension's code:

```
import SpriteKit

internal extension SKScene {

func nodeWithTexture(atlas: SKTextureAtlas, texture: String, name: String) -> SKSpriteNode {
    let nodeTexture = atlas.textureNamed(texture)
    let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: nodeTexture)
    node.name = name
    return node
  }
}
```

Now, my problem with this is that I can't use the method in my scene's initilizer. It's giving me a super.init error that I don't understand.

This is the error I got when I try to use the extension inside the init before the `super.init(size: size)` call.

[image]

And this one is the error I got when I try to use it after super.init(size) call.

[image]

### Question Update

I workaround my problem using the next approach thanks to Nate's answer.

First I initialize all the stored properties at the declaration moment:

```
let background = SKSpriteNode()
```

Then I call the extension method after the `super.init(size: size)` call and everything is set:

```
super.init(size: size)
background = nodeWithTexture(atlas, texture: "bg", name: "background")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An initializer needs to give initial values to *all* stored properties before calling `super.init()`, and has to call `super.init()` before it can call any other instance methods.

You can solve this in one of two ways:

1. Declare `background` as an implicitly unwrapped optional —`nil` is an acceptable initial value for an optional, so you could put your call to `nodeWithTexture()` after `super.init()`.

   ```
   var background: SKSpriteNode!
   ```
2. Declare background as a lazy property — if it's always going to be based on `atlas`, you could declare it this way:

   ```
   lazy var background: SKSpriteNode = self.nodeWithTexture(self.atlas, texture: "bg", name: "background")
   ```

Comment: You've been too fast :) My (now deleted) answer is pretty much the same as yours. I would add a 3rd option (which I don't like though): initialize `background` with a dummy value, and then reinitialize it properly after the initialization is completed.

Comment: I'd say nil is a good dummy value—part of the idea behind Swift optionals is to avoid the use of sentinel values.

Comment: Your answer helped me to understand how the initialization works but I used another approach to solve it (post updated), I would love some feedback about it.